# Pass data from activity to fragment with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have an activity and 2 fragments on it, this activity got value from intent and I want to pass this value to a fragment, but when I do this with

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment).commit()
```

it overrides fragments on each other,(I have a fragment and bottomnavbar)
I think there should be a better way, for example passing data without replacing, but when I do this there is no value given to fragment.
Activity Code: `

```
        val bundle = Bundle()
        val fragment = ResultFragment()
        bundle.putString("BMI", bmi)
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment).commit()
```

Fragment code:

```
val data = arguments
val value = data?.getString("BMI")
```

I tried using different ways to navigate between fragments, but did not work.

Comment: are you want to send data from activity to fragment @WuLo

Comment: @SurajkaranMeghwanshi yes

Comment: "for example passing data without replacing" -- if the fragment already exists, call a function on the fragment. Or, update a shared viewmodel, and have the fragment observe the changes from the viewmodel.

Comment: No need to pass data between activity to fragment if you have sharedViewmodel, Use SharedViewmodel for data passing.

Comment: What is my point that , before navigate to any specific fragment save data in temp veriable in sharedViewmodel, after you replaced fragment use that updated value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while getting data in fragment use requireArguments()

```
if (arguments != null) {
    if (requireArguments().getString("BMI")) {
         // your code
 }
```